# Select elements in array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

x[1, x.size - 1]
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```

How do I rewrite this code to make it more elegant.
I would like something like

```
x[1, -1]
```

Comment: what are you trying to attempt here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) accepts a [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) instance, and the right boundary can be negative, specifying the amount of elements *from the end*:

```
x[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead.

```
x[1..-1]
```